# Wordpress move custom wp_users field to wp_userneta

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I had a developer long ago set an extra field on the user signup page. Im not sure how exactly he did it, but I now have an extra column in the **wp_users** table called "**hear_from**". I'd like to move the data in this column to the **wp_usermeta** table.

What would be the sql command to move existing data from **wp_users** to **wp_usermeta** (match id for id)?

The tricky part is that i did not start using this field initially so many of my first users have NULL instead of a value.

Answer (score -1):

write below code in one php file and run it on root location of your site..

```
include 'wp-load.php';
$qry = "SELECT * FROM wp_users";
$res = $wpdb->get_results($qry, ARRAY_A);
foreach($res as $key=>$val){
$user_id = $val['ID'];
$hear_from = $val['hear_from'];
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (
`umeta_id` ,
`user_id` ,
`meta_key` ,
`meta_value`
)
VALUES (
NULL , '$user_id', 'hear_from', '$hear_from'
);
");
}
```